# Ionic 4 modal is never removed from the DOM

Tags: ionic-framework, modalviewcontroller, ionic4

I have one modal where there is a function executed each seconds.
When I call modal.dismiss, in the console log I can see the function is still executed.
I don't know why the modal is not totally removed and destroy after been dismissed.

Any help is welcome.

Alex.

Comment: Hi! Can we have a look at your code please?

Comment: You have to remove timer or intervals or subscription in onDestroy hook

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer :

```
if(this.intervalTimer) {
clearInterval(this.intervalTimer)
}
```

Modal was destroyed from the dom but I was forgetting to clear the Interval..